# ValidationSummary and ValidationMessageFor with custom CSS shown when no errors present

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Once I applied custom CSS to ValidationSummary and ValidationMessageFor it appears on the page even when there are no errors. The CSS does have an image.

How do I hide the summary and errors when there are no errors?

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "required" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, null, new { @class = "required" })


.required {
    background-image: url(/images/required.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 33px;
    width: 386px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1eb4ec;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 54px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are already built in css types for these:

```
/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

in the default css file for MVC3 projects. These are shown appropriately based on if the `ModelState` has any errors for the `Property` specified or any at all for `ValidationSummary`. If no errors are present in the `ModelState` then the `display:none;` from `.field-validation-valid` will hide the errors.

Comment: Perfect, i modified the built in css styles. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

We don't put a class of required on our ValidationMessagesFor helpers

```
<li>
                    <label for="NameFirst">First Name <span>* Required</span></label>
                    <span class="field-container">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { required = "required", data_type="name" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    </span>
                </li>
```