# How to display styled text with <span> in MVC Html.ValidationSummary()?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, validation, methods, helper

Is there a way to display something more then plain text using MVC Validation helper methods?
I tried to display somthing like this:

Controller:

```
string msg = "Error <span style='color:blue;'> bla bla bla</span>";
ModelState.AddModelError("model", msg);
```

View:

```
<span ...>@Html.ValidationSummary()</span>
```

But I get plain text:

```
"Error <span style='color:blue;'> bla bla bla</span>"
```

instead of "Error " and **blue** "bla bla bla":

I tried to pass as msg:

```
var msg2= MvcHtmlString.Create(msg);
var msg3= new HtmlString(msg);
var msg4= msg3.ToHtmlString();
```

But it helps nothing.

Interesting, when I use FireBug, and edit UL / LI tag generated by @Html.ValidationSummary() it can display such styles.

Of course - I can change style of validation css: - but it change whole text generated by helper method - which is not what I want.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has already beeen answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899609/validationsummary-and-validationmessagefor-with-custom-css-shown-when-no-errors

Comment: Armen Abrami, it is not the answer to my question - the link you provide is about styling whole text of validated message. My question is how to "say" to browser to parse text with tags - not to display it as plain text.